# Why isn't this question "too broad?"

Tags: discussion

[Is Mary's virginity evidence that sex is always sinful?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/708/is-marys-virginity-evidence-that-sex-is-always-sinful)

and

[What do Christians mean by a "personal relationship" with Jesus?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/470/what-do-christians-mean-by-a-personal-relationship-with-jesus)

Both of these question leave the doctrine open ended.

Answer (score 1):

**2011.** Didn't they wear bell-bottom pants back then too?

In retrospect, much of known history was a bad idea. They say hindsight is 20/20, but just because we have more fashion sense now<sup>1</sup> doesn't always mean defrocking the [*faux pas*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faux_pas) of the past is necessarily a good idea. As a general rule it is not.

Now if those same unsightly pants go parading around our home page we might have to consider send them back to the dressing room.

Since the activity that floated them up last week was not the usually buzzards around a limping question but rather ordinary activity that could happen anywhere and they have dropped off the radar again I not inclined to anything about them. Usually when really bad old stuff hits the home page it will attract trouble for a while. I don't see a need to create some where none got going on its own.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Ya right!</sub>

Comment: They showed up on top of the "Active" questions which is what brought them to my attention.  I understand that our rules have changed via evolution (pun intended), I was unclear if we wanted to go back in time and fix things.  Potentially someone will use a question like that as an example of a good question to ask - which if they were posted today, they would not be.

Comment: @TheFreemason They have also both already washed out of the active question list making it likely they won't be causing a scene. One got there for getting a junk answer (not the kind that bad questions attract, just junk) and the other because an OP updated his answer. These aren't causes for concern, but I have protected both questions anyway. That helps for popular but not-so-exemplary old questions.

Comment: By what standard do you say that wearing bell-bottom pants is bad? I thought opinions were not allowed here.

Comment: @Jay [This is meta. Opinions are about the only thing you'll find here](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta). Besides I was just making an analogy. If you wear or appreciate bell-bottoms you might want to mentally substitute another analogy.

Comment: How do you do superscripts and subscripts and move pictures around?

Comment: @Anonymous Edit a post that uses them to see how they were done. There are lots of ways but I combine HTML subscript and superscript tags.

Comment: What if it's a blog post?